# Eclipse Content Assist - Enable auto activation

Tags: android, eclipse

I am into **Eclipse -> Preference -> Jave -> Editor -> Content Assist**.

[image]

I have enabled auto activation and have set delay time to **0**. But how get auto completion working without writing anything, even "."? Just as in XCode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/FAQ#Can_I_enable_code_completion_to_be_activated_as_I_type_like_how_it_works_in_Visual_Studio.3F